# EmberJS test fails first time running in phantomjs

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-simple-auth

## Problem

I have a `/login` route that uses `ember-simple-auth` to implement authentication. During testing `ember-cli-mirage` is used to mock the backend. The user logs in by providing their email address and password.

In total I have 4 acceptance tests for this route, similar to the test below:

```
test('should show error message for invalid email', function(assert) {
  visit('/login');
  fillIn('input#email', 'invalid-email');
  fillIn('input#password', 'invalid-password');
  click('button.button');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(find('div.notification').text(), "Invalid email/password");
  });
});
```

When I run the tests using `ember t` only the first test in the file fails. If I comment this test out, the next one fails, and so on. If I run the tests in server mode with `ember t -s` the same test fails; however, when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> to re-run the tests, all the tests pass.

The failure message is always the same, shown below:

```
not ok 7 PhantomJS 2.1 - Acceptance | login: should show error message for invalid email
    ---
        actual: >

        expected: >
            Invalid email/password
        stack: >
            http://localhost:7357/assets/tests.js:22:19
            andThen@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48231:41
            http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48174:24
            isolate@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:49302:30
            http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:49258:23
            tryCatch@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68726:20
            invokeCallback@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68738:21
            publish@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68709:21
            http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48192:24
            invoke@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:10892:18
            flush@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:10960:15
            flush@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:11084:20
            end@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:11154:28
            run@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:11277:19
            run@http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:32073:32
            http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:48783:24
        Log: |
```

After all the tests have run, test emits an exception:

```
# tests 60
# pass  59
# skip  0
# fail  1
Not all tests passed.
Error: Not all tests passed.
    at EventEmitter.getExitCode (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/lib/app.js:434:15)
    at EventEmitter.exit (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/lib/app.js:189:23)
    at /home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/lib/app.js:103:14
    at tryCatcher (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/jon/projects/jonblack/wishlist-web/node_modules/testem/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:637:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
```

It seems odd that this is emitted for tests failing rather than just reporting the test failure, so perhaps it's related.

Running the tests in Firefox and Chromium work, as does running the application in development mode and logging in manually. The problem is limited to phantomjs.

I have other acceptance tests for another route and these all pass. It seems limited to the `/login` route, suggesting that it is possibly related to authentication.

## Debugging

I've tried debugging by adding `pauseTest()` to the test and `"phantomjs_debug_port": 9000` to `testem.js` but both Firefox and Chromium do nothing when I use the debug console. This might be my lack of experience debugging phantomjs, but I would at least expect it to give me an error - it literally does nothing.

It feels as though there is a timing issue between phantomjs and something, possible ember-simple-auth, in my Ember app.

I'm not that experienced debugging phantomjs problems nor Ember acceptance test failures, so any help is appreciated.

## Versions

```
ember-cli 2.10.0
ember-simple-auth 1.1.0
ember-cli-mirage 0.2.4
```

## Update 1

The button is inside a `login-form` component:

```
<form {{action 'login' on='submit'}}>
  <p class="control has-icon">
    {{input value=email id='email' placeholder='email' class='input'}}
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  </p>
  <p class="control has-icon">
    {{input value=password id='password' placeholder='password'
            type='password' class='input'}}
    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
  </p>
  <p class="control">
  <button class="button is-success" disabled={{isDisabled}}>Log In</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

The component's login action just calls the passed in login handler:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  email: "",
  password: "",

  isDisabled: Ember.computed('email', 'password', function() {
    return this.get('email') === "" || this.get('password') === "";
  }),

  actions: {
    login() {
      var email = this.get('email');
      var password = this.get('password');
      this.attrs.login(email, password);
    }
  }
});
```

Which is the `authenticate` method in the login controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    authenticate(email, password) {
      this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', email, password).catch((data) => {
        this.set('errors', data['errors']);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

## Update 2

As suggested by Daniel I added a delay to the test:

```
test('should show error message for invalid email', function(assert) {
  visit('/login');
  fillIn('input#email', 'invalid-email');
  fillIn('input#password', 'invalid-password');
  click('button.button');
  andThen(function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      assert.equal(find('div.notification').text(), "Invalid email/password");
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

Using only `Ember.run.later` the test still failed, but putting that inside the `andThen` causes it to pass. Have you noticed the bizarre part? **The delay is 0 milliseconds.**

I still want to find an explanation for this because I don't trust that this will run the same on whatever machine the tests run on.

## Update 3

Today I had a surprise: suddenly the tests were working again!

I added a new route with acceptance tests. The route itself is an authenticated route, so the tests use the `authenticateSession` test helper from ember-simple-auth to authenticate.

**when I remove the tests that use this helper, the error returns!**.

I'm not sure what this means. It feels like the issue is with ember-simple-auth, but it might also be a giant coincidence that the helper resolves another timing issue.

Down the rabbit hole we go...

## Update 4

Below is the configuration for the auth endpoints in ember-cli-mirage:

```
this.post('/token', function({db}, request) {
  var data = parsePostData(request.requestBody);

  if (data.grant_type === 'password') {
    // Lookup user in the mirage db
    var users = db.users.where({ email: data.username });
    if (users.length !== 1) {
      return new Mirage.Response(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {
        errors: [{
          id: 'invalid_login',
          status: '400',
          title: 'Invalid email/password',
        }]
      });
    }
    var user = users[0];

    // Check password
    if (data.password === user.password) {
      if (!user.active) {
        return new Mirage.Response(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {
          errors: [{
            id: 'inactive_user',
            status: '400',
            title: 'Inactive user',
          }]
        });
      } else {
        return new Mirage.Response(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }, {
          access_token: 'secret token!',
          user_id: user.id
        });
      }
    } else {
      return new Mirage.Response(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {
        errors: [{
          id: 'invalid_login',
          status: '400',
          title: 'Invalid email/password',
        }]
      });
    }
  } else {
    return new Mirage.Response(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, {
      errors: [{
        id: 'invalid_grant_type',
        status: '400',
        title: 'Invalid grant type',
      }]
    });
  }
});

this.post('/revoke', function(db, request) {
  var data = parsePostData(request.requestBody);

  if (data.token_type_hint === 'access_token' ||
      data.token_type_hint === 'refresh_token') {
    return new Mirage.Response(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  } else {
    return new Mirage.Response(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                               {error: 'unsupported_token_type'});
  }
});
```

## Update 5

Here's my `config/environment.js` file:

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'wishlist-web',
    environment: environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
    }
  };

  if (environment === 'development') {
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {
    ENV.ServerTokenEndpoint = 'http://localhost:9292/token';
    ENV.ServerTokenRevocationEndpoint = 'http://localhost:9292/revoke';
    ENV.ApiHost = 'http://localhost:9292';
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

Comment: When you clicked the `button.button`, how do you create a promise? Can you provide the code that creates the promise? (My guess is the promise cannot be resolved in phantomjs environment.)

Answer (score 1):

You have few things to try here to debug this issue.

1. You could remove `{{isDisabled}}` from button to make sure it's not disabled when you try to click it.
2. Use setTimeout instead of andThen and see if it's timing issue.
3. Replace authenticate action code with nothing, to make sure it isn't causing your test to fail.

You could also **rewrite** test to put your assert.ok after some event in JavaScript. For example you could mock authenticate action or observer errors property. You can do this by using lookups or registers in acceptance environment - tests from one of my Ember CLI addons could help you - [ember-link-action/tests/acceptance/link-action-test.js](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/ember-link-action/blob/master/tests/acceptance/link-action-test.js).

## Edit

Having seen what worked for you experience tells me that you should try 2 things.

For this code:

```
andThen(function() {
    Ember.run.later(this, function() {
      assert.equal(find('div.notification').text(), "Invalid email/password");
    }, 0);
  });
```

You could try `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => { ... assert here }` instead of using `Ember.run.later`. Or you could try using just `Ember.run` instead of `Ember.run.later`.

Conclusion: The key to fixing this issue could be putting your assertion in Ember Run Loop.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I have a component test for `{{isDisabled}}` and that works fine; removed it anyway and it didn't help. Using the second option I was able to get the test to pass (by delaying the assert with `Ember.run.later`, but I still needed to use `andThen`. I've updated my question because this feels like it could easily break (e.g. if the CI server is under load and the delay isn't high enough). I still want to get to the root cause.

Comment: Just noticed something bizarre: with the delay is set to 0 milliseconds it works.

Comment: Hey Jon, I've updated answer because you have found something very interesting. ;) I'm curious if it helps...

Comment: Neither `Ember.run.scheduleOnce` nor `Ember.run` helped, sadly. It could be that the invocation of `Ember.run.later` still takes long enough even with a 0ms delay, but I'm grabbing at straws here.

Comment: Did you try to re-write test to lookup controller:login, addObserver for 'errors' on it, and in that observer INSIDE `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', ...)` run the assertion?

Comment: I'm afraid your last comment is beyond my skills. Could you add an example to you answer? I'd love to try it. I've also updated the question again with another discovery!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the error you're seeing (`Invalid email/password`) is the (mock) server response and indicates something is wrong with either the mock or the credentials you're using in the test.

I'd also not use mirage for mocking the authentication request. mirage (just like Jason API) is resource based and not something that's well suited for authentication.

Comment: Yes, the "Invalid email/password" message is from the mock (ember-cli-mirage). I've updated the question to include the configuration for this. I agree ember-cli-mirage isn't well suited to mocking non-resource-based endpoints, but I'm not aware of anything else and it wasn't that much effort. Do you think this could be the cause? Could this explain why the test passes when another test with ember-simple-auths `authenticateSession` helper is run first?

Comment: Can you share your `config/environment.js` as well?

Comment: Added my `config/environment.js`. As far as I can see, only the production settings are new, but those shouldn't be used during testing.